# Is there a VisualStudio / Resharper warning / error I can turn on to catch unprocessed IDisposables?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, idisposable, roslyn-code-analysis

When using [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET) it is common to find methods that return [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx). It is very rare that these IDisposables can be ignored and if done so will cause memory leaks and bizarre program operations.

There is [CA1806 - Do not ignore method results](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182273.aspx) but that is too general for a programming language like C#. I would just like to mark unprocessed IDisposables as a fatal error.

I will often write code like this in the constructor of a custom user control

```
this.LoadUnloadHandler
    ((CompositeDisposable c) =>
    {

        this
            .Events()
            .GotFocus
            .Subscribe
            (e =>
            {
                if (EntitySelectorManager == null)
                    return;
                EntitySelectorManager.ActiveSelectorControl = this;
            })
            .DisposeWith(c);

        this
            .WhenAnyValue(p => p.Selection)
            .WhereNotNull()
            .Subscribe(selection => ItemsSource = MakeListText(selection));
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // OOOOPS I forgot to add a DisposeWith(c) here..
        // The subscription will leak
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////


        // Handle the case of an empty list box not
        // being able to get focus.
        this.Events().PreviewMouseDown
            .Subscribe
            (e =>
            {
                if(Items.Count==0)
                    Focus();
            })
            .DisposeWith(c);

        // Remove the list selection on lost focus.
        this.Events().LostFocus
            .Subscribe
            (e => SelectedIndex = -1)
            .DisposeWith(c);


    });
```

where *DisposeWith* is just an extension method to add an IDisposable to a CompositeDisposable. All
generated IDisposables should be added but the compiler at the moment does not check this for me.

So to be specific. Is there a built in Roslyn Analyzer / a Resharper Analyzer or an open source
analyzer than can catch this and fail my build or do I have to write one from scratch?

Comment: i'm not sure about automated checks but the general way you should use an IDisposable is inside a using statement, the only time you shouldn't is when the disposables lifecycle is larger than the current contexts lifespan which is very rare and probably indicative of a mistake on the programmers part

Comment: No. You are thinking about lexical scoping of IDisposable. It is not always the correct pattern. I generate a load of IDisposables when a user control is displayed and when it is removed from the visual tree / hidden I need to dispose them to avoid resource leaks. The scoping is time based not lexical.